# Filtering IDS which has the same elements in a list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have grouped columns and got the following sample dataframe. After this I would like to filter IDs which has identical elements in a list.

df

```
ID     Value
1      [0,0,50,0,0]
2      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
3      [0,100,0,0,50]
4      [0,0,0,0,0]
```

I would like to filter `IDs` which has same elements in a list under `Value` columns and those elements must be only 0s.

The expected output is just IDs and it should be 2 and 4.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Help with what exactly? What did you try and looking to help for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare sets by `set([0])`:

```
df1 = df[df['Value'].map(set).eq(set([0]))]
print (df1)
   ID                  Value
1   2  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3   4        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If need filter only same values per list compare lengths in [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df2 = df[df['Value'].map(set).str.len().eq(1)]
```